# Apigee: Add login with an existing OAuth 2.0 id-provider

Tags: apigee

I have an admin-console for an existing service that I want to provide access to by adding login, using our company's OAuth 2.0 service. I want to use Apigee here, so that the web-app with the admin-console does not have to implement the login-logic.

My idea was to use AuthorizationCode flow and let Apigee manage the tokens and I looked into https://github.com/apigee/api-platform-samples/tree/master/sample-proxies/oauth-login-app, but I really can't see how our existing OAuth service fits in.

Is there a sample like that? Perhaps using Google's or Facebook's OAuth service to authenticate the user?

Comment: So basically you're wanting to authenticate users of the admin-console by integrating with your existing oauth 2.0 service?  How you integrate depends on a few things: what grant_types are supported by your existing oauth 2.0 service?  Is the admin console server-side or client-side? Any reason for thinking about having apigee mint a token when a token will already exist from existing oauth 2.0 service?

Comment: Correct. The admin console is hosted server-side and we use the authorization code flow in the oauth server. I am not totally sure I understood your last question though - the idea is to authenticate the user in apigee. I don't need the user info in the admin-webapp, all I want to do is to restrict access to the admin console to our employees, without writing any additional code in the admin-webapp. For the service that it is administrating (our product), there is also a user login, but for that we use another oauth service ( Google login) - decoupled from this.

Answer (score 1):

First, Apigee needs to be a proxy into the admin-console.  This means that all traffic to the admin-console has to go through Apigee.  Otherwise, you won't be able to enforce authentication.

Second, there are a couple different options for integrating with the external oauth 2.0 service.  Apigee has the ability to store an external access token and use it as its own, or Apigee can generate a token and store the external access token as a custom attribute.

**High level thoughts on how the Apigee proxy could look like:**

`ProxyEndpoint` - endpoint exposed to clients connecting to admin console
`TargetEndpoint` (not shown in that oauth login-app example) - endpoint for the actual admin console

The flows that execute in the Apigee proxy before sending the request to admin-console will need to implement logic that checks an authentication token.  If it's valid, let the request pass onto the TargetEndpoint (admin-console).  If the request isn't valid, step through logic that goes calls the external oauth 2.0 server's auth code flow.  This will require the following:

1. Apigee needs to be registered with external oauth 2.0 server.
2. Logic needs to be built in this proxy to support the redirection based flow of  authorization code grant_type (obtaining auth code, receiving the auth code, obtaining token --> all while being redirection based and transparent to user).
3. In addition to #2, Apigee will need to store the external token as custom attribute and expose the apigee token, or store the external token for verification purposes later on.  http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/authorize-requests-using-oauth-20 (see Delegating token management).  After the token is stored, you'd need to respond with another 302 redirect to the initial uri + token so the request can pass through to admin-console as an authenticated request.

#2 isn't exactly straight-forward and there won't be an example proxy that shows this implementation.  If the oauth 2.0 service supported a password grant, it may simplify the implementation, but allows the credentials to pass through apigee and not directly with the authorization server.